# bash + regular expression + validate machine name

Tags: bash, regular-expression

How to match the following hostnames with a bash regular expression?

My Linux hostnames are: star01 , star02 , star03 , start04.

My goal is to validate the string "start0" with any second number

I do the following:

```
 [[ $hostname =~ star0[:digit:]  ]] && echo ok
```

but this isn't working:

```
hostname=star04
[[ $hostname =~ star0[:digit:]  ]] && echo ok
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: you have some "star" vs "start" terms in your question; can you confirm that they're all exactly how you want them? One hostname (start04) and the goal sentence "start0" have `t`'s in them, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posix character class should be specified as `[[:digit:]]`:

```
[[ $hostname =~ star0[[:digit:]] ]] && echo ok
```

---

The alternative simplified approach would be:

```
[[ $hostname =~ star0[0-9] ]] && echo ok
```

---

> `[:digit:]` is a *POSIX* character class, used inside a bracket
>   expression like `[x-z[:digit:]]`. The *POSIX* character class names
>   must be written all lowercase.